Inbetween UDF in Excel VBA but make it account for decimals instead of just integers?
I have this VBA function to return the values inbetween two numbers into a single cell. It functions properly with negative numbers as well. It does not however properly return values in between decimals rounded to the nearest integer.
Eg, In between 3.5 and 6.5 the cell should print 4,5,6 when currently it just prints: 5
Function InBetween(MyFirst As Integer, MyLast As Integer)
Dim foo As String
Dim i As Long
foo = MyFirst + 1
For i = MyFirst + 2 To MyLast - 1
foo = foo & "," & i
Next i
InBetween = foo
End Function


If the 1st number is 3 and the 2nd is 5, is the expected result 3,4,5, just 4 or something else?

@VBasic2008 result is just 4

"rounded to the nearest integer" - rounding works differently in VBA vs on the worksheet.  In VBA Round(x, 0) for x=3.5 is 4, but for x=6.5 is 6 ("Banker's Rounding") On a worksheet ROUND() always rounds up from x.5   Which rules do you want?

@TimWilliams 3.5 should be 4 and 6.5 should be 6. So I shouldnt say "nearest integer" but what you said above. the integers without those bounds set by x

Your problem is that your parameters are declared as Integer. When you call the function with Decimals (likely Double), the VBA runtime will convert the arguments implicitly to Integers. To make matters worse, VBA uses "Bankers Rounding", if you pass "5.5", it will be rounded to 6, but "6.5" will also be rounded to 6.
So change the parameter types to Double. Now you can use the Int-function to get only Integer-Part of the starting number, which is something different than rouding:  Int(3) is 3, Int(3.3) is 3, Int(3.7) is 3.
Function InBetween(MyFirst As Double, MyLast As Double)
    MyFirst = Int(MyFirst)
    (...)
End Function 

This works, however I find it a little hard to read as it doesn't seem very obvious what the starting and ending values for the For-Loop is. I came up with the following code instead:
Function InBetween(MyFirst As Double, MyLast As Double)
    Dim foo As String
    Dim curVal As Long
    curVal = Int(MyFirst) + 1
    Do While curVal < MyLast
        foo = foo & IIf(foo = "", "", ",") & CStr(curVal)
        curVal = curVal + 1
    Loop
    InBetween = foo
End Function


Deleted my post; you hit essentially everything I did (though i used application.round() rather than int(), which doesn't seem to benefit the end goal, plus you sorted the "," in-line, which is nicer than the if-statement i used.

Instead of OP's solution, repetition of comparison in every loop scan is obvious in this solution.

Delimited Integers Between Two Numbers

Function InBetween( _
    ByVal MyFirst As Double, _
    ByVal MyLast As Double, _
    Optional ByVal Delimiter As String = ",") _
As String
    
    If MyFirst = MyLast Then Exit Function

    Dim nStart As Long, nEnd As Long, nStep As Long
    
    Select Case MyFirst
        Case MyLast: Exit Function
        Case Is < MyLast
            nStep = 1
            nStart = Int(MyFirst) + 1
            nEnd = Int(MyLast)
            If nEnd = MyLast Then nEnd = nEnd - 1
        Case Is > MyLast
            nStep = -1
            nStart = Int(MyFirst)
            If nStart = MyFirst Then nStart = nStart - 1
            nEnd = Int(MyLast) + 1
    End Select
    
    Dim Result As String, i As Long, IsFirstFound As Boolean
    
    For i = nStart To nEnd Step nStep
        If IsFirstFound Then
            Result = Result & Delimiter & i
        Else
            Result = i
            IsFirstFound = True
        End If
    Next i
    
    If IsFirstFound Then InBetween = Result

End Function


This should do what you want
Function InBetween(MyFirst As Double, MyLast As Double) As String
    Dim i As Long, sep As String
    'round up first value, round down second value
    For i = Application.Ceiling(MyFirst, 1) To Application.Floor(MyLast, 1)
        InBetween = InBetween & sep & i
        sep = "," 'populate separator after first value
    Next i
End Function


It's a smart trick with the empty separator initially, but sep = "," performs every time which I don't like.

Could always use If Len(sep)=0 Then sep = "," but what would we really be saving there?

Nothing here, but OP's foo = MyFirst + 1 looks not bad.

Focusing on doubles, we forgot about integers.

Let me to participate too.
Option Explicit

Function InBetween(BtwFrom As Double, BtwTo As Double) As String
    Dim s&, e&
    s = Application.Ceiling(BtwFrom, 1): If s = BtwFrom Then s = s + 1
    e = Application.Floor(BtwTo, 1): If e = BtwTo Then e = e - 1
    If e >= s Then
      InBetween = Application.Evaluate("TEXTJOIN("","",FALSE,SEQUENCE(" & (e - s + 1) & ",1," & s & "))")
    End If
End Function

The solution uses the power of Excel to generate the sequence of integers and join them into a string over comma.
